# Rails: is it possible to define virtual attribute through associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pg, virtual-attribute, pg-search

I have two models:

`Skillnames` and `Skills`

`User` can create `skillname` and `skill`, in `skills model` I have a reference "`skill_id`" which means when I do `Skillname.where(:id => @skill.skill_id)` it will give me back the name.

Now I'm super confused over something. I have created a search using `PG_Search` and using `associated_against`,Now I can search the Skill for the user using the skill_id (which is not so smart) 
I was wondering if I can create something like this in the model of the skill:

virtual attribute:

```
  def skillname=(skillname)
    Skill.where(:skill_id => Skillname.where(:name => skillname).first.id)
  end
```

update: adding the models:

```
class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch
    attr_accessible :user_id, :skill_id
    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :search, against: [:first_name, :last_name,:country],
                  :associated_against => {
                      :skills => :name,
                    }

end

class Skillname < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch
    belongs_to :user
    attr_accessible :user_id, :description, :name



end
```

Comment: Can you please show us your models?

Comment: why skillname and skill, why not just 1 model with a name attribute ?

Comment: to avoid redundancy of the skillnames, I have already provided a list of names in the skillname tables. The user only needs to get the id,

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady maybe you are right, am over-complicating this :/! Ah

Comment: what kind of redundancy are you expecting ?

Comment: having the names on both tables ?

Comment: I don't really understand the relation between skill name and skill, they isn't any association in the models